# Passing ArrayList<Person> to new activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I want to pass ArrayList to new activity, in the new activity I will load the list with ArrayAdapter.

But I can not transfer the object to the new activity I am getting null on the new activity.

I have read that I need to implement serialization to the Person class...
Is this the only way?

Here is my code:

AsyncTask onPostExecute I am getting the array.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Person> personArrayList){

        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ResultsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("personArrayList",personArrayList);
        activity.startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Sending it with putExtra.

Here is the Activity which suppose to receive the array.

```
public class ResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        ArrayList<Person> personArrayList = (ArrayList<Person>) intent.getSerializableExtra("personArrayList");

        PeopleAdapter adapter = new PeopleAdapter(this, personArrayList);

        // Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
        // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
        // activity_results.xml layout file.

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


        // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link WordAdapter} we created above, so that the
        // {@link ListView} will display list items for each {@link Person} in the list.
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

So on the receiving end the ArrayList is empty. Ideas?

Comment: yes ,you need to implement Serializable on Person class

Comment: Try like this, when getting the intent in ResultsActivity.                                      
  personArrayList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("personArrayList");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You transfer this ArrayList by making your class `Person` implement the `Parcelable` interface. Once that's done all you need to do is write:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Person> personArrayList){

    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ResultsActivity.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("personArrayList",personArrayList);
    activity.startActivity(intent);

}
```

In your ResultsActivity class, you get this array by writing `intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("personArrayList")`

Hope this helps.

Comment: You mean this ?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: Yes, that's what he meant

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to implement `Serializable` on your `Person` class.

`ArrayList` is serializable, but if its content is not, then it will be not possible to serialize/deserialize it.

Simply add `implements Serializable` to your class and you are good to go.

Comment: I have added this line before posting,
public class Person implements Serializable {
It did not help, I think you need to implement some methods as well.
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: Can you please provide the code for `Person` class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variables for this type of scenario using application class to set and get values.But please note that it is not entirely reliable solution.

For setting the values

```
((ApplicationClassName)getApplicationContext()).setDataArrayList(personArrayList);
```

For retrieving the values

```
ArrayList<Person> personArrayList =((ApplicationClassName)getApplicationContext()).getDataArrayList();
```